# How to detect if the mouse if over a point in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener

I'm using MouseListener and I can figure out how to detect if I move my mouse over I point in my JFrame.

Comment: check cordinates using if condition

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html

Comment: `MouseMotionListener` is what you are looking for, but understand, if you frame contains other components which have any kind of `MouseListener` attached, they will consume the mouse events and your frame will not be notified...

Answer (score 0):

Add a label on the J Frame and add mouse listener to the Jlabel